# Strength of the magnetic field question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

due to a current $I $ amp in a wire in the form of a circle of radius $r$ cm, at a point $x$ cm from the center of the circle is given by

$$H=\frac{\pi(I)(r^2)}{5(r^2+x^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{ gauss}.$$

If $I = 10$ and $r= 4$, find the approximate change in $H$ when $x$ changes from $3\,\mathrm{cm}$ to  $2.9\,\mathrm{cm}$.

I'm sorry for the long question but I'm 35 years old taking a Calculus class for the first time ever, and I don't think this question my instructor gave me is a math question! My friend said it's Physics so I was looking for help, can anyone help me??

Comment: The physics is all done. I expect your instructor either wants you to do some arithmetic, or wants you to find a slope and use that to estimate the change. Think about $\Delta H\simeq\frac{dH}{dx}\Delta x$.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate H by plugging in the numbers given for the two values of x. The answer is the difference between them.